# Consultar qué registro no está en otra tabla pero discriminado por fechas, con mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Voy a ejemplificar la situación que tengo:

- la tabla *personas* con *IdPersona* y *NombrePersona*
- la tabla *asistencias* con *id*, *fecha* y *IdPersona* (registra la asistencia de personas en determinada fecha)

Necesito saber las personas que NO asistieron, discriminadas por fecha, es decir de cada fecha registrada en asistencias en vez de mostrar los asistentes, debo mostrar las inasistencias.

He probado con un `not in` y subconsultas pero no llego a obtener los datos correctos.
Por ejemplo hago

```
Select personas.idpersona, personas.nombrepersona, asistencias.fecha
from personas, asistencias
where personas.idpersona not in (select asistencias.idpersona)
```

pero llega un momento en que todos alguna vez asistieron en algún momento, y no devuelve ningún campo.

Comment: Es decir, por cada fecha mostrar las personas que no tienen asistencia en esa fecha?

Comment: si, por cada fecha que existe en la tabla asistencia mostrar los que NO asistieron esa fecha, que en otra fecha pueden haber asistido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener todos los elementos menos los que asistieron.

Para obtener todas las tuplas puedes usar:

```
-- todos
select distinct fecha, nombrepersona
from asistencias
         cross join persona;
```

Para obtener los que asistieron por cada fecha:

```
-- los que asistieron
select fecha, nombrepersona
from asistencias
         natural join persona;
```

Finalmente, une las dos querys con un `where`, obteniendo:

los que no fueron = todos los que pueden ir **menos** los que si fueron.

```
-- los que no asistieron
select distinct fecha, nombrepersona
from asistencias a
         cross join persona p
where (a.fecha, p.idpersona) not in (select fecha, idpersona
                                     from asistencias
                                              natural join persona);
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma posible es generar una "grilla" de fechas por cada persona, esto es la combinación o producto cartesiano ente todas las posibles personas y fechas:

```
select p1.idpersona,
       a1.fecha
       from (select distinct fecha from asistencias) a1
       cross join personas p1
```

Esto nos da lo planificado, lo que debemos hacer ahora es compararlo con la realidad representada por `asistencias`, en aquellos casos dónde no se cumpla la relación con la anterior consulta, estaremos frente a una ausencia.

```
select p.idpersona,
       p.nombrepersona,
       f.fecha
       from (select p1.idpersona,
                    a1.fecha
                    from (select distinct fecha from asistencias) a1
                    cross join personas p1
       ) f
       left join asistencias a
          on f.fecha = a.fecha
          and a.idpersona = f.idpersona
       inner join personas p
          on p.idpersona = f.idpersona
       where a.fecha is null
```

**Importante**: La "grilla" o cronograma la estamos generando directamente desde `asistencias`, por que es todo lo que puedo conocer a partir de tu pregunta, esto no es lo ideal, seguramente en tu caso tengas en otra tabla el cronograma con los días ya definidos y deberías usar la misma. Esta solución no va a indicar como ausencia  aquel caso en el que todas las personas faltaron cierto día.

Aquí tienes [un ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=025b1a88728cd8f21f31996e170a2632) para verificar.